# WS2812b/Sk6812 flickering on camera

Tags: led, led-strip, led-driver

As far as I understood, the WS2812b or SK6812 LEDs use PWM output to drive the diodes. This could cause flickering on camera when the LEDs are dimmed.

- Does anyone know the output driver PWM rate?
- Is there any known issue with flickering on camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments to Justme's answer:

> This is what I don't understand: WS2812B data sheet says the data rate is 800 kb/s and one RGB data package is 24 bits long. That means one LED will get new RGB values with 33 kHz.

Almost. There's a reset pulse to be taken into account too, but applications with a single addressable LED would be rare as a cheap common anode RGB LED could be used instead. For longer chains of LEDs the maximum update rate would be 33 kHz / # of LEDs.

> This would be then way more than the 400 Hz for the physical LED output current.

The two rates would, most likely, be independent. The data will be latched when it's received and applied to the PWM controller at the start of the next PWM cycle. From the point of view of the camera the data rate will be irrelevant.

> A PWM rate of 400 Hz means that the shutter speed of the filming camera must be lower than 1/400, correct?

No, higher than 1/400 (2.5 ms) but I think that a lower number in the denominator is what you meant.

Be careful with this. If you match the PWM duty cycle exactly then it would be fine but at slightly longer cycles there would be variation.

```
       ________          _________           _________          _________
PWM __|        |________|         |_________|         |________|         |______
        ____________________             ____________________
CAMERA_|                    |___________|                    |__________________
         1.5 PWM cycles                      1 PWM cycle
```

*Figure 2. Variations in light captured by the camera depending where in the PWM cycle the shutter is triggered.*

To avoid this problem you would need to ensure that the exposure time was long enough to include at least, say, five PWM cycles.

Comment: with a refresh rate of 400Hz and a brightness of 8bit, it would mean the internal clock is about 100kHz. Anyways, any camera shutter speed lower than 1/400 should be fine then. When shooting at 24fps, typical shutter speed is 1/50, so there should be no flickering of the LED, even at lowest dimming.

Comment: @F.Heisenberg Did you read the last sentence in Transistor's answer? **No** you can not say that "any shutter speed lower than 1/400 should be fine".

Comment: @elliot: the answer was posted after i raised this question

Answer (score 0):

WS2812B datasheet says PWM rate is not less than 400 Hz.

SK6812 datasheet says PWM rate is typically 1200 Hz.

Depending on the camera and the type of shutter it has, it may be visible or not.

Comment: This is what I don't understand: WS2812b data sheet says the data rate is 800kb/s and one RGB data package is 24 bits long. That means one LED will get new RGB values with 33kHz. This would be then way more than the 400Hz for the physical LED output current.

Comment: Is this the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle?

Comment: a PWM rate of 400Hz means that the shutter speed of the filming camera must be lower than 1/400, correct?